# How does inode->i_cdev of the cdev's fops->open function's argument contain the driver's main control structure?

Tags: linux, linux-device-driver

I was looking at Xilinx PCIe XDMA driver, and became curious how the `inode->i_cdev` field of fops's open function contains the pointer to the xcdev structure. The xcdev encloses the cdev and other important information, and the fops's open function then keeps this pointer(=xcdev) of the main control structure in the filp's private_data pointer to use it in other fops functions.

https://github.com/Xilinx/dma_ip_drivers/blob/9f02769a2eddde008158c96efa39d7edb6512578/XDMA/linux-kernel/xdma/xdma_cdev.c#L163

In the above code, in what mechanism, the xcdev pointer is connected to the inode->i_cdev? I guess sometimes the inode->i_cdev contains the cdev itself but here it containts the pointer to the upper struct which containts cdev. I think I once understood how this works but I can't figure it out now.

**ADD(solved)**
As Tsyvarev said in the comment, the inode->i_cdev points to the cdev in this case too. I made a mistake and got confused. (it points cdev and the S/W used container_of to get the upper struct).

Comment: "I guess sometimes the inode->i_cdev contains the cdev itself but here it containts the pointer to the upper struct which containts cdev." - Actually, `inode->i_cdev` contains the pointer to `cdev` structure. The pointer to the `xdma_cdev` is obtained using `container_of` operation.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Ah, thank you. you are correct, that was my mistake. So I'm relieved my understanding so far wasn't wrong. (and if you put a simple answer with this, I can choose it)